# How to keep Number Format in a Variant data type

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I have an `APF` variable store in columns `apf_rev_info_col`
I set up its format number with 1 decimal number like this:

`Columns(apf_rev_info_col).NumberFormat = "0.0"`

Then I want to pick up unique value from this columns, using `Application.Unique` like this

`unique_info = Application.Unique(Range(Cells(first_row + 1, apf_rev_info_col), Cells(last_row, apf_rev_info_col)))`

but `unique_info` is a variant and its only keep the value of APF if APF has .0 as decimal number.

I tried `unique_info(1, i).NumberFormat = "0.0"` but Subscript out of range.
What can I do to keep the NumberFormat in unique_info, please?

Comment: Format and the underlying value of a cell are two separate things. You might consider using `Format$`, as `.NumberFormat` is the property of a `Range`, and `unique_info` is not a `Range`.

Comment: Yes exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much @bigben. it works like this:         `unique_info(u, 1) = Format(unique_info(u, 1), "0.0")`

Comment: Note now that you have a `Variant/String`, not a `Double`.

Comment: Sorry for getting back in this question, but I have a case when I have only 1 `APF` so `unique_info` has only 1 element, `unique_info(1) = Format(unique_info(1), "0.0")` doesn't work. Can you help me please? @BigBen

Comment: Try `Format$(CDbl(unique_info(1)), "0.0")`.